Export a model from FeynRules
I would like to write a new BSM model with FeynRules and then draw the corresponding Feynman diagrams and compute the amplitude with FeynArts, so I have created a new folder called "NM", which is inside "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.3\AddOns\feynrules\Models" and then inside the folder "NM" I have created a file called "NM.fr", which containes the specifics of the new scalar fields S[1] and S[2].
The code I have written in mathematica is the following:
$LoadAddOns["FeynArts"];
$FeynRulesPath = SetDirectory["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\13.3\\AddOns\\feynrules"];
<< FeynRules`;
$FAVerbose = 0;
SetDirectory["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\13.3\\AddOns\\feynrules\\Models\\NM"];
LoadModel["NM.fr"];
WriteFeynArtsOutput[LPhi4, ModelName -> "NM"];
top2To2 = CreateTopologies[0, 2 -> 2];
feynman = InsertFields[top2To2, {S[1], S[1]} -> {S[2], S[2]}, InsertionLevel -> {Classes}, Model -> FileNameJoin[{"NM", "NM"}]];
Paint[feyman, ColumnsXRows -> {3, 1}, Numbering -> None, SheetHeader -> None, ImageSize -> {768, 256}]

I do not get in output the Feynman diagrams but only
Paint[InsertFields[CreateTopologies[0, 2 -> 2, ExcludeTopologies -> {WFCorrections}], {S[1], S[1]} -> {S[2], 
S[2]}, InsertionLevel -> {Classes}, Model -> NM\NM], ColumnsXRows -> {3, 1}, Numbering -> None, SheetHeader -> None, ImageSize -> {768, 256}].

How can I solve it?

It appears that CreateTopologies didn’t work. It seems to be unrecognized.

In your code you misspelled feynman as feyman, so you must not have copied and pasted.

Yeah, I have misspelled feynman, but also writing it correctly the output is the same. Do you have any idea on how to solve the problem with CreateTopologies? Because if I load FeynArts and FeynRules using <<FeynArts' and <<FeynRules', I get in output the Feynman diagrams but I have problems with variable shadowing. By loading FeynArts as I wrote in the question I solve the problem of variable shadowing but I do not get in output anything.

Sorry, I don’t use these packages. But here I see “Please send bug reports, suggestions, fan mail, etc. to Thomas Hahn, hahn@feynarts.de.” And here, “Questions can be posted in the forum.”
